# Masking the special pages in mediawiki

Tags: php, .htaccess, mediawiki

We are developing a application using mediawiki. we are not fully aware of mediawiki. We have created a **special page** as **mediawiki/Special:Video**. But we do not like to view the word **Special:** in our url. i.e., we would like to view the url as **mediawiki/Video** instead of **mediawiki/Special:Video**. If are not aware of mediawiki functions fully. So kindly let us know how to do this url masking in mediawiki. I have tried like this

```
   Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^ajax.php($|/) - [L]

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /var/www/

RewriteRule ^mediawiki/video$ mediawiki/Special:Video

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(/?[^/]*)$ /mediawiki/index.php?title=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /mediawiki/index.php?title=$1&actions=$2 [L]
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it as follows, no need to use `RequestCond`

```
RewriteRule ^mediawiki/Video$ /mediawiki/Special:Video
```

Comment: can you post your full `.htaccess` file

Comment: thanks DevZer0 now it is working fine. I forget to add rewrite base in my file

Comment: @Kalai why you did that for?

Comment: it was worked not because of that,i have used the extension tag as a video so it was displayed that page. Still it is not getting resolved.

Comment: I posted my full htaccess please check and let me know the possiblities

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33828/discussion-between-kalai-and-devzer0)